# map struct with array variable to struct with explicit variables

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, struct

Assuming I've got the following `struct A` definition from a subcontractor:

```
struct A {
  int var0;
  int var1;
  int var2;
};
```

I cannot change anything about it but I have to use this struct for the call to the subcontractors API. In my calculation components I'll use a more generic version called `struct B`:

```
struct B {
  int var[3];
  int other_vars[3];
  // [...]
};
```

Given these, I am looking for a simple way to map the array `var` from my more generic `struct B` to the explicit variable declarations of `struct A`.

The current implementation is simple as stupid

```
a.var0 = b.var[0];
a.var1 = b.var[1];
a.var2 = b.var[2];
```

which produces a very large mapping file and perhaps failures in the future, if `struct A` gets an update.

#### Possible Solutions:

I thought about something like memcpy, but I think that is very unsafe..

```
#define MAP(from, to, var) \
    std::memcpy(&to.var##0, &from.var, sizeof(from.var));

MAP(b, a, var);
```

[Online GDB with this example](https://onlinegdb.com/eH8hYnj2k)

#### Sidenotes:

- The structs are much bigger than shown here. There are a bunch of different variables defined that way with much higher indexes.
- Due to the fact that the code for `struct A` is generated by the subcontractor (we get the generated `.h` file), I cannot guarantee that the variables are in the right order and not intermitted by other variables. That's why my possible solution is not good enought in my opinion.

Comment: If both structures are aligned/padded correctly `memcpy()` should work?

Comment: While it's likely that the `int` members of `struct A` will follow each other in memory, it's not guaranteed. There may be padding between the members.

Comment: if `A` is generated code, cant you also generate the mapping?

Comment: Have you tried std::bit_cast ?

Comment: Unless the `A` structure contains complex declarations, why not create your own script or preprocessor-type program to read and parse the structure, and generate the code for mapping/copying other structures to the `A` structure?

Comment: Yes, you are both right. Generating the mapping code with some small script is very simple. I just wanted to make sure that I don't miss something obvious that could work reliable without an extra script.

Comment: If the member names really have very predictable patterns, Boost.Preprocessor might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the members of struct A map to struct B::var in the same order, memcpy is the best way to do this. B both structs are 'standard-layout' types, they are guaranteed to occupy contiguous bytes of storage.

From C++ standard :

> An object of trivially copyable or standard-layout type shall occupy contiguous bytes of storage.

To deal with any potential padding issues that may make this process unsafe; static assertions can be used to ensure everything lines up as expected.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
  int var0;
  int var1;
  int var2;
  // int var3; // Adding this variable will cause static_assert to fail.
};

struct B {
  int var[3];
  int other_vars[3];
  // [...]
};
// Note: for B to be trivially-copyable or standard-layout, all the members must also be.
static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value);
static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable<B>::value);
static_assert( std::is_standard_layout<A>::value);
static_assert( std::is_standard_layout<B>::value);
static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(B::var), "Incompatible mapping to subcontractor.");
```

Again, this only works so long as struct A doesn't change so that A::var0 should now map to B::var[1] or some non-contiguous order.